# Debugging Jasmine Custom Matcher Messages

Tags: jasmine, e2e-testing

I have the following code for a Jasmine Custom Matcher, as described [here](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/custom_matcher.html):

```
jasmine.addMatchers({
            testingFunction: function(util, customEqualityTesters) {
                return {
                    compare: function(actual, expected) {
                        if (expected === undefined) {
                            expected = '';
                        }

                        var result = {};

                        result.pass = util.equals(actual.myValue, 1, customEqualityTesters);

                        if (result.pass) {
                            result.message = "Passed";
                        } else {
                            result.message = "Failed";
                        }

                        return result;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

And calling it as such:

```
.then(function() {
    expect({
        myValue: 1
    }).testingFunction();
})
```

During debugging, I see that execution goes to my custom matcher but for some reason, neither my Pass or Fail messages get printed to the console.

Any ideas as to why this might be?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else that may be running into this issue, I figured out that in my `jasmineNodeOpts`, I was overriding the `jasmine` print method as such:

```
// Overrides jasmine's print method to report dot syntax for custom reports
//print: () => {},
```

Removing that fixed my issue.